# Removing special character when regex matched

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a file like test.l

```
car ( "kia"
max speed
min speed
price "XXX"
)
bike ( "R1"
max speed
min speed
price "YYY"
)
```

I want to remove the quotes in the line having 'price'.
I have been trying to do that using :

```
use strict;

open FILE, "<<test.l";
#open (FILE2,">>test.l");

while (my $string = <FILE>) {

    if ($string =~ m/^price/ig) {

        $string =~ s/\"//ig;
        print  FILE $string;
    }
}
close FILE;
#close FILE2;
```

Can i overwrite the input file with the modified line when 'price' is encountered???
The above code just print the input without any change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not really possible. You have to create a temporary file. This following trick will create the temporary file for you:

```
local @ARGV = 'test.1';
local $^I = '';          # Use .bak on Windows
while (<>) {
   s/"//g if /^price/;
   print;
}
```

It's basically the same as doing

```
perl -i -pe's/"//g if /^price/' test.1
```

Comment: @ysth, `tr/"//d`, I think? I never use it.

Comment: I had to reread the question a couple of times to understand what you were referring to as being not possible. Still not clear for me.

Comment: @Zaid, He wants to read from and write to a single file. Generally, speaking that's not possible (or at least complex and crazy slow), although I suppose it would be in this case since he's always replacing with something shorter. So I recommended he write the output to a temporary file and rename it over the old one, and showed how to do that easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'if(/^price/){s/\"//g;}print' your_file
```